# Populate MySQL database from postgresql dump file

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, pg-dump

Actually I need to populate MySQL database from a SQL file which was generated by postgresql as

```
pg_dump dbname > myfile.sql
```

So, if I try to do like

```
mysql> source myfile.sql
```

This obviously does not work. Although it did populate 70% tables but I want to know is there a way to achieve it ?

From the source file of postgresql, can I source and populate my database of MySql.

Comment: This really depends on the datatypes you're using, and whether you're using custom functions and triggers. In addition, you'll certainly have to port the code that uses those tables, possibly with difficulty. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17132/2129

Comment: @Bruno: We dont have any triggers or dependency on the database in the code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to migrate the data and structure from postgres table to mysql equivalent, the easiest way is using a database conversion tool like : [ESF Data Migration Toolkit](http://www.easyfrom.net/) or the opensource counterpart [openDBCopy](http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/) .

If you don't want or you can't use a migration tool, and you need to only migrate data, another simple way could be export data in CSV format from PostgreSQL and then import it in MySQL, so you can do it with some commands like :

**ON Postgres (Export):**

```
COPY (SELECT query) TO '/path to csv file -*.csv';
```

**ON Mysql (Import):**

```
load data infile 'path to csv file-*.csv' into table tablename fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' .
```

If you anyway want to proceed with the dump tool(pg_dump) you can add this options to produce a dump file that MySQL can understand better :

```
-d --data-only --no-owner --no-acl --attribute-inserts --disable-dollar-quoting --no-tablespaces
```

Keep in mind that, depending on the structure of the source database, you could have to manipulate the dump file to allow MysQL to understand the generated dump file ...

Comment: I dont have neither the schema nor the data for MySql, although I only have my database populated.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to migrate without loosing data is to use Mysql Workbench migrations. This [tutorial](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/how-to-migrate-postgresql-databases-to-mysql-using-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/) explains how to do the migrations. Few things not mentioned in the tutorial that I found to be important are below:

- Install latest postgres drivers to connect source postgres database, how to install this driver can be found in this [tutoria](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/set-up-and-configure-postgresql-odbc-drivers-for-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/):
- Download and install the postgres odbc drivers from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/)
- After installation you will see the drivers in "Open ODBC Administrator" 
          1. [image]
          2.
- Use "PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)" as the driver while setting up the source postgres database
  [image]

**Note: using "PostgreSQL ANSI(x64) " as driver gives error while migrations . May be because my data contains unicode characters.**

Comment: Requires oracle login.

Comment: link for postgresql driver is broken. just use chocolatey: `choco install psqlodbc -y`