# Conversion of postgres dump to mysql dump in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, postgresql, converters

I want to convert postgres dump to mysql dump without using workbench. Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate database from Postgres to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909223/migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql)

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462044/populate-mysql-database-from-postgresql-dump-file

Comment: maybe this works? idk https://www.pukkapanel.com/guide29/convert-postgresql-dump-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard, which was introduced in MySQL Workbench 5.2.41.

There's a blog post on the MySQL Workbench site here that details how to perform a migration.

Note that it will not be able to migrate more complicated database features.

Comment: please read the question again. It says "without using workbench".